# What is the new annotation of scope = ScopeType.PAGE?

Tags: java, jsf, seam

does someone know what the new (jee6) annotation for `scope = ScopeType.PAGE` is? I cannot find docs according this :(
ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `@ViewScoped` in `JSF 2.0`.